# configuring nginx to serve static json files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Switching to nginx for a site, one issue I'm having is serving up static json files.

I added to the mime types:

```
application/zip                         zip;
...
application/json                        json;
...
```

and restarted but it tried serving it up as a download (ie `http://domain.com/json-tmp/locations.json`). What else would I need to configure?

thx

Comment: I think it doesn't know what to do with this file type and serves it back. Trying to download on Safari, Chrome, and FF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this post is quite old but adding application/json mime type to nginx configuration file plus restarting the server should work.

When you request the json file try to debug the response header and check if the Content-Type header was successfully changed to application/json.

Answer (score 5):

I had to add

```
    application/json                      json;
```

in `/etc/nginx/mime.types` and restart nginx to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try serving it as javascript ...

```
application/javascript                json;
```

Or as plain text ...

```
text/plain                            txt json;
```

I'll try the javascript first.